# adding rows not working due to unterminated string constant error

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add the following rows in the table?

I am having error of

> unterminated string constant with the following code

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>

$('#myTable tbody').append('<tr style="display: table-row;">
    ' <td style="width: 250px;">
                <select id="List" class="FixedWidth" onclick="this.style.width='auto';" onchange="this.blur();" onblur="this.style.width='250px';" style="display: none;">
                <div id="labelDiv"><label id="ComboBoxText"></label></div>
                <input id="TID" name="TID" type="hidden" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="Cell KeyCell" style="display: none;">
                <input class="KeyInput" id="Key" maxlength="5" name="Key" placeholder="Hours" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"><br>
                <textarea maxlength="2000" class="NameInput" cols="20" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="enter here" rows="2" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></textarea>
                <input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0">
            </td> </tr>'
    )
```

Comment: You need to escape your single quotes

Comment: Take a look at the code you posted here. The syntax highlighting should jump out at you. You've mixes your single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code . concept of string concatenation

```
 '<td style="width: 250px;">'+
       '<select id="List" class="FixedWidth" onclick="this.style.width=\'auto\'" onchange="this.blur()" onblur="this.style.width=\'250px\'" sty"display: none;">'+
               ' <div id="labelDiv"><label id="ComboBoxText"></label></div>'+
                '<input id="TID" name="TID" type="hidden" value="0">'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td class="Cell KeyCell" style="display: none;">'+
               ' <input class="KeyInput" id="Key" maxlength="5" name="Key" placeholder="Hours" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"><br>'+
 '<textarea maxlength="2000" class="NameInput" cols="20" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="enter here" rows="2" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></textarea>'+
                '<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0">'+
            '</td>'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is you didnt use string concatenation and the way you have given this.style.width=auto; is also wrong.i hope this helps :

```
$('#myTable tbody').append(
     ' <td style="width: 250px;">'+
       '<select id="List" class="FixedWidth" onclick="this.style.width=auto;" onchange="this.blur();" onblur="this.style.width=250px;" sty"display: none;">'+
               ' <div id="labelDiv"><label id="ComboBoxText"></label></div>'+
                '<input id="TID" name="TID" type="hidden" value="0">'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td class="Cell KeyCell" style="display: none;">'+
               ' <input class="KeyInput" id="Key" maxlength="5" name="Key" placeholder="Hours" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"><br>'+
 '<textarea maxlength="2000" class="NameInput" cols="20" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="enter here" rows="2" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></textarea>'+
                '<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0">'+
            '</td>'

    )
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/11cjEGd83tDOZwHaHB4p?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the line breaks by putting a `\` at the end of each line, and also your single quotes by putting `\'` instead of `'`.

JavaScript expects a string to be terminated in the same line it starts - that's why it says "unterminated string...". To tell it that it goes on, you will have to escape the line break. That's what the backslash is for.

This code will work:

```
$('#myTable tbody').append(
    ' <td style="width: 250px;">\
                <select id="List" class="FixedWidth" onclick="this.style.width=\'auto\';" onchange="this.blur();" onblur="this.style.width=\'250px\';" style="display: none;">\
                <div id="labelDiv"><label id="ComboBoxText"></label></div>\
                <input id="TID" name="TID" type="hidden" value="0">\
            </td>\
            <td class="Cell KeyCell" style="display: none;">\
                <input class="KeyInput" id="Key" maxlength="5" name="Key" placeholder="Hours" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"><br>\
                <textarea maxlength="2000" class="NameInput" cols="20" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="enter here" rows="2" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></textarea>\
                <input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0">\
            </td>'
    );
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is the only complete answer on this page.

Comment: Really? :) look at the top

Comment: By the time I wrote this comment. ;)

Comment: Ur answer is "Now" correct. I would like u to get 3 upvotes more to surpass Pranavs's answer,

Comment: U just gave "\" on last character of each line . Will u please tell us reason ??

Comment: JavaScript expects a string to be terminated in the same line it starts. To tell it that it goes on, you will have to escape the line break. That's what the backslash is for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make all this `html` to one line OR `break` these huge string using `concatination` operation `+` like below

```
$('#myTable tbody').append(

    ' <td style="width: 250px;">'+
                '<select id="List" class="FixedWidth" onclick="this.style.width=\'auto\'" onchange="this.blur()" onblur="this.style.width=\'250px\'" style="display: none">'+
                '<div id="labelDiv"><label id="ComboBoxText"></label></div>'+
                '<input id="TID" name="TID" type="hidden" value="0">'+
            '</td><td class="Cell KeyCell" style="display: none">'+
                '<input class="KeyInput" id="Key" maxlength="5" name="Key"'+ 'placeholder="Hours" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"><br>'+
                '<textarea maxlength="2000" class="NameInput" cols="20" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="enter here" rows="2" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></textarea>'+
                '<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0"></td>'
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to escape your single quotes with a `\`

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>

$('#myTable tbody').append(
    ' <td style="width: 250px;">
                <select id="List" class="FixedWidth" onclick="this.style.width=\'auto\';" onchange="this.blur();" onblur="this.style.width=\'250px\';" style="display: none;">
                <div id="labelDiv"><label id="ComboBoxText"></label></div>
                <input id="TID" name="TID" type="hidden" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="Cell KeyCell" style="display: none;">
                <input class="KeyInput" id="Key" maxlength="5" name="Key" placeholder="Hours" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"><br>
                <textarea maxlength="2000" class="NameInput" cols="20" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="enter here" rows="2" style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></textarea>
                <input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0">
            </td>'
    )
```